# bulls and cows game -- programming algorithm(python)

Tags: python, algorithm

**This is a simulation of the game [Cows and Bulls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows) with three digit numbers**

I am trying to get the number of cows and bulls between two numbers. One of which is generated by the computer and the other is guessed by the user. I have parsed the two numbers I have so that now I have two lists with three elements each and each element is one of the digits in the number. So:

237 will give the list `[2,3,7]`. And I make sure that the relative indices are maintained.the general pattern is:`(hundreds, tens, units)`.

And these two lists are stored in the two lists: `machine` and `person`.

## ALGORITHM 1

So, I wrote the following code, The most intuitive algorithm:

`cows` and `bulls` are initialized to 0 before the start of this loop.

```
for x in person:
    if x in machine:
        if machine.index(x) == person.index(x):
            bulls += 1
            print x,' in correct place'
        else:
            print x,' in wrong place'
            cows += 1
```

And I started testing this with different type of numbers guessed by the computer.

Quite randomly, I decided on 277. And I guessed 447. Here, I got the **first** clue that this algorithm may not work. I got 1 cow and 0 bulls. Whereas I should have got 1 bull and 1 cow.

This is a table of outputs with the first algorithm:

```
Guess        Output            Expected Output

447     0 bull, 1 cow          1 bull, 0 cow 
477     2 bulls, 0 cows        2 bulls, 0 cows
777     0 bulls, 3 cows        2 bulls, 0 cows
```

So obviously this algorithm was not working when there are repeated digits in the number randomly selected by the computer.

I tried to understand why these errors are taking place, But I could not. I have tried a lot but I just could not see any mistake in the algorithm(probably because I wrote it!)

## ALGORITHM 2

On thinking about this for a few days I tried this:

`cows` and `bulls` are initialized to 0 before the start of this loop.

```
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
            if x == y and machine[x] == person[y]:
                bulls += 1
            if not (x == y) and machine[x] == person[y]:                   
                cows += 1
```

I was more hopeful about this one. But when I tested this, this is what I got:

```
Guess        Output            Expected Output

447     1 bull, 1 cow          1 bull, 0 cow 
477     2 bulls, 2 cows        2 bulls, 0 cows
777     2 bulls, 4 cows        2 bulls, 0 cows
```

The mistake I am making is quite clear here, I understood that the numbers were being counted again and again.

i.e.: 277 versus 477

When you count for bulls then the 2 bulls come up and thats alright. But when you count for cows:

1. the 7 in 277 at units place is matched with the 7 in 477 in tens place and thus a cow is generated.
2. the 7 in 277 at tens place is matched with the 7 in 477 in units place and thus a cow is generated.'

Here the matching is exactly right as I have written the code as per that. But this is not what I want. And I have no idea whatsoever on what to do after this.

### Furthermore...

I would like to stress that both the algorithms work perfectly, if there are no repeated digits in the number selected by the computer.

Comment: If the target is 277 and the guess is 447, shouldn't the expected output be 1 bull, 0 cows?  Why do you expect 1 bull, 1 cow?  Note that the rules specified in the wikipedia article state that all digits should be different.

Comment: This is fun.  :-)  But I think your expected outputs are inconsistent: if you expect 1 bull, 1 cow for 477, then you should expect 2 bulls one cow for 777.  I would personnaly change 447's expected output to 1 bull, 0 cows.

Comment: Your first algorithm is wrong because of `machine.index(x) == person.index(x)`.  The `index` function returns the index of the *first* occurrence.  So `[2, 7, 7].index(7)` is equal to 1.  And `[4, 4, 7].index(7)` is equal to 2.

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question appropriately. It should be 1 bull and 0 cows. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
def digits(number):
    return [int(d) for d in str(number)]

def bulls_and_cows(guess, target):
    guess, target = digits(guess), digits(target)
    bulls = [d1 == d2 for d1, d2 in zip(guess, target)].count(True)
    bovine = 0
    for digit in set(guess):
      bovine += min(guess.count(digit), target.count(digit))
    return bulls, bovine - bulls
```

Note that `bulls_and_cows(277, 447)` will return 1 bull and 0 cows.  This what I would personally expect: why would the first 7 in 277 count as a cow since there's already a bull for 447's 7?

Comment: You are right! and this works! and thanks a lot! this is a very elegant way of doing it!

Comment: Glad you like it, I had fun with this question. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`.index()` returns the index of the first occurrence of the input given:

```
>>> [1, 5, 5].index(5)
1
```

You should use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead to get all possible indexes:

```
>>> for i, j in enumerate([1, 5, 5]):
...     if j == 5:
...             print i
... 
1
2
```

---

However, it seems this can be done with `zip()`, unless I'm mistaken:

```
for x, y in enumerate(zip(player,computer)):
    if y[0] in computer and not y[0] == y[1]:
        print y[0], "is in the number"
        cows += 1
    elif y[0] == y[1]:
        print y[0], "in the correct place"
        bulls += 1
    else:
        print y[0], "is not in the number"
```

With `player = [4, 4, 7]`:

```
4 is not in the number
4 is not in the number
7 in the correct place
>>> cows
0
>>> bulls
1
```

With `player = [4, 7, 7]`:

```
4 is not in the number
7 in the correct place
7 in the correct place
>>> cows
0
>>> bulls
2
```

Comment: zip will definitely help you find the bulls, but not the cows. Additional logic would be needed here.

Comment: exactly! @E_net4. Can you help with the cows part?

Comment: sorry! please see the edit in the question. it should be 1 bull and 0 cows. you obtained 1 bull and 1 cow! sorry!

Comment: @IcyFlame Sorry! That was an error in the formatting of my answer. My solution is still correct

Comment: Hey! I get the answer from your code too, But I just understood @MiniQuark 's answer better! So I accepted that..! Sorry!

Comment: Sorry... :'( I just like his answer better..!

Comment: @IcyFlame Lol it's fine :D

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is an algorithm which compares digits and positions.
I use it in a program for finding the target in a 4-digit 
version of the game when the target can begin with "0". 
It works with or without repeating digits equally well.
In the table below are shown all 9 results/values of variable 
ED (Equal Digits) when comparing digits in each position of  
the guess 447 with each digit of the target 447, for the 
special case when the guess G$(3) equals the target T$(3)*.
For any other case the table is different and the values for 
B and C will change accordingly. 
It's a fact that for us, humans it's easier to count 
Bulls and Cows without repeating digits. 
With repeating digits I need to see the table below.
        !!!Important!!! 
Do not judge the values for B and C. Just use them. 

    4  4  7       3 Bulls      3 Cows
   --------        (I=J)       (I<>J)
 4| 1  1  0       1  .  .      .  1  .   
  |                    
 4| 1  1  1       .  1  .      1  .  1
  |                      
 7| 0  0  1       .  .  1      .  .  .



Here is the algorithm in Liberty BASIC:
'-------------------------------------
[calculate_Bulls_and_Cows]
B = 0: C = 0
        FOR I=1 TO 3
            FOR J=1 TO 3
                ED=(T$(I)=G$(J)) 'finding Equal Digits makes ED=1
                B = B+ED*(I=J)   'Bulls increment when ED*(I=J)=1
                C = C+ED*(I<>J)  'Cows increment when ED*(I<>J)=1
            NEXT J
        NEXT I
return
'------------------------------------
_________

*In this case I decided Digits to be considered 
text variables because of some benefits when 
it wasn't restricted the target to begin with "0".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def game(a,b,c,d):
    from random import randint
    m=randint(0,9)
    n=randint(0,9)
    o=randint(0,9)
    p=randint(0,9)
    cow=bull=0
    A={a:m,b:n,c:o,d:p}
    k=A.keys()
    v=A.values()
    bull=cow=0
    for i in k:
        if i==A[i]:
            bull+=1
        elif i in v:
            cow+=1
    if (cow>0 or bull>0):
        print(bull,"Bull and ",cow,"Cow")
    print("Correct No. :       ",m,n,o,p)
    print("You've Entered : ",a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey the best way to make a cow bull program is to play with characters and strings rather than numbers. Then you will not have to bother about hundred's or ten's places. You can follow my tutorial on 4 digit cow-bull game in python: http://funpythonprojects.blogspot.in/2013/07/cow-bull-game-aka-guess-number-in-python.html

Comment: the basic thing that i am trying to solve is the occurence of a repeated digit. And one of the conditions of your game is that the number should not have a repeated digit. So does not really work for me!

Answer (score -1):

## bulls and cows(the code is kinda begineerish, just started learning from youtube)

```
import random

def num_checker(guess_num,answer):
    guess_num=list(str(guess_num))
    ans=list(str(answer))
    cow=0
    bull=0
    for a in range(0,4):
        if guess_num[a]==ans[a]:
            bull+=1
            ans[a]=10#changed values to counter reccuring digits
            guess_num[a]=20#changed values to counter reccuring digits

    for a in range(0,4):
        for b in range (0,4):
            if guess_num[a]==ans[b]:
                cow+=1
                ans[b]=30#changed values to counter reccuring digits
                break

    final=[bull,cow]
    return final

#..................................................
ans=random.randrange(1000,10000)
print("this is the program to gues a four digit number")

#......................................................#continue asking until you get it right
while True:
    print("just for reference answer is:",ans)
    num_typed=int(input("please guess a four digit the number?\n "))
    reply=num_checker(num_typed,ans)
    if reply==[4,0]:
        print("correct")
        print(reply[0],"bull",reply[1],"cows and the ans is",ans)
        break
    else:
        print(reply[0],"bulls",reply[1],"cows")
```